# How do I loop through a list by twos?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, iteration

I want to loop through a Python list and process 2 list items at a time. Something like this in another language:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.length(); i+=2)
{
   // do something with list[i] and list[i + 1]
}
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 490, accepted):

You can use a `range` with a step size of 2:

**Python 2**

```
for i in xrange(0,10,2):
  print(i)
```

**Python 3**

```
for i in range(0,10,2):
  print(i)
```

**Note:** Use `xrange` in Python 2 instead of `range` because it is more efficient as it generates an iterable object, and not the whole list.

Comment: +1.  It's worth noting that you're describing Python 2's xrange and range.  In Python 3, range() generates an iterable object.

Comment: in Python 3, range() has an optional step size and xrange() no longer exists

Comment: what about about float value? I got error that `integer argument expected, got float`

Comment: @KevinPatel Just do int(your_float_var) perhaps?

Comment: @RoelVandePaar, No that is still an integer. Actually I found the answer. `import numpy as np` `for i in np.arange(-3.14, 3.14, 0.1): print (i)`

Comment: @KevinPatel you could divide step each time, without numpy. `for i in range(-31, 31, 1): print(i//10)`

Answer (score 141):

You can also use this syntax (`L[start:stop:step]`):

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i in mylist[::2]:
    print i,
# prints 1 3 5 7 9

for i in mylist[1::2]:
    print i,
# prints 2 4 6 8 10
```

Where the first digit is the starting index (defaults to beginning of list or 0), 2nd is ending slice index (defaults to end of list), and the third digit is the offset or step.

Comment: This will work very well, as long as the `list` isn't huge. If the `list` _is_ huge, you're making a copy of it when you use the slicing syntax...

Comment: Your answer is good for me when using parameter: `range(my_param)[::2]`

Comment: I like that the range is implied with this.  You don't have get the length of the list to compare that against a variable.

Comment: This is the best answer for me, in my preset list every second item is info for the previous(main items). I need to loop only through the main items. This answer realy does it.

Answer (score 85):

The simplest in my opinion is just this:

```
it = iter([1,2,3,4,5,6])
for x, y in zip(it, it):
    print x, y

Out: 1 2
     3 4
     5 6
```

No extra imports or anything. And very elegant, in my opinion.

Comment: This doesn't quite do what this question asks for.

Comment: Sure it didn't fit the question exactly, but it does do exactly what I was after. Nicely too.

Comment: Why to use `iter`, it is not neccessary?

Comment: This does not answer the OP.

Comment: @PascalVKooten it won't work as intended without iter

Comment: Yea I see, my comment was wrong. The iter makes it so that the object is iterated in turn.

Comment: Refer to `zip(*[iter(s)]*n)` at https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip, more groups is possible.

Comment: be aware, you might miss last element if the list length is odd

Comment: @Jerry you can use from `itertools.zip_longest()` if the length of the list is an odd number.

Answer (score 46):

If you're using Python 2.6 or newer you can use the grouper [recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) from the [**`itertools`**](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Call like this:

```
for item1, item2 in grouper(2, l):
    # Do something with item1 and item2
```

Note that in Python 3.x you should use `zip_longest` instead of `izip_longest`.

Comment: +1 This is the method the documentation itself suggests.

Comment: just in case you are wondering how it works, consider all iterators in args advance together so that izip will always take next element when invoking next() on its arguments

Answer (score 7):

```
nums = range(10)
for i in range(0, len(nums)-1, 2):
    print nums[i]
```

Kinda dirty but it works.

Comment: Considering that `range`/`xrange` have built in support for changing the increment value, this solution seems kind of silly.

Comment: Umm, that's what the the last parameter to `range` is doing...

Comment: It's presumed that nums is a sequence we have no control over.  The demonstration really begins subsequent to the first line where I assign `nums` a value.

Answer (score 3):

This might not be as fast as the izip_longest solution (I didn't actually test it), but it will work with python < 2.6 (izip_longest was added in 2.6):

```
from itertools import imap

def grouper(n, iterable):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG') --> ('A,'B','C'), ('D','E','F'), ('G',None,None)"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n

    return imap(None, *args)
```

If you need to go earlier than 2.3, you can substitute the built-in map for imap. The disadvantage is that it provides no ability to customize the fill value.

Answer (score -2):

If you have control over the structure of the list, the most pythonic thing to do would probably be to change it from:

```
l=[1,2,3,4]
```

to:

```
l=[(1,2),(3,4)]
```

Then, your loop would be:

```
for i,j in l:
    print i, j
```

Comment: It's a property being read in from an external file. I can't control the list and I actually am trying to change it from `l=[1,2,3,4]` to `l=[(1,2),(3,4)]` which is why I'm asking the question