# Multiplying every second number in a list

Tags: python

I need to be able to multiply every second number in a list by 2 so say:

```
List = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want this to return `[1,4,3,8]` but all the ways that I have tried it such as

```
credit_card = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

credit_card[::2] = [x*2 for x in credit_card[::2]]

print(credit_card)
```

If i input the same list from before it returns `[2,2,6,4]`

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through a Python list by twos?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990121/how-do-i-loop-through-a-python-list-by-twos)

Comment: Just a handy tip for you: Avoid naming your variables using built-in names such as `list`, `dict`, `id`, etc.. (here you used big `L` so its not such a problem, but a variables `should_look_like_this` and `ClassesAreWrittenLikeThis`. Makes code more readable and saves you headaches down the road

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, you just need to start from the second (1-indexed) element:

```
credit_card[1::2] = [x*2 for x in credit_card[1::2]]
```

That said, since you seem to be implementing the [Lunh checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm), you only need a sum of those digits without having to update the original data, like done in [this example](http://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers#Python).

Comment: Just a short explanation for OP: the general syntax is `credit_card[start:stop:step]`. `[::2]` would mean "Take all elements from start to stop with step of 2 and `[2::2]` would mean "start at 3rd element, go to the end, with step of 2

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

new_lst = [2*n if i%2 else n for i,n in enumerate(lst)]     # => [1, 4, 3, 8]
```

Comment: I think you can minimize even more if you use `1*x = x` and not `0 = False` :-)

Comment: I don't understand how your comment has anything to do with my answer?

Comment: Ah... that would work, and might be (very slightly) faster due to not branching. But I think the reduction in readability outweighs any code length or speed improvements :-/

Comment: just to comment that two properties worth remembering can "solve" this :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
credit_card = input().split()
for x in len(credit_card)
    if x % 2 != 0
        credit_card[x] = credit_card[x] * 2

print (credit_card)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using enumerate:

```
[i* 2 if p % 2 else i for p, i in enumerate(l)]
```

where **i** is the **p-th** element of **l**.

Comment: Good answer. Just change `item` to `i` (now, it won't work) :)

Comment: @spoor, @Nander Speerstra: what is the purpose of the `%` operator?

Comment: @Jon. You basically check if the position is even or odd by checking if the remainder of the division by 2 is 0 (even) or not (odd).

Comment: @sopor: so the reason you can say `if p % 2` instead of `if p % 2 == 0` is because Python takes the 0 value as a truthy value and 1 as a falsy value... right? Meaning that 0 passes the `if` and any other value fails it

Comment: @Jon, now: if the index is **odd**, use **p*2** (**else**: **p**). If you say `if p % 2 == 0`, you would have to **reverse** the `if/else`: `i if p % 2 == 0 else i*2`. Now you say: if the index is **even**, print **p** (**else**: use **p*2**). It's a matter of what you like to be in the `if` and the `else`...

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra: Right -- got that backwards. What I meant to ask was whether `if p % 2 == 1` is equivalent to `if p/2 == 1` ... or in other words, what does the `%` operator do?

Comment: No: `8/2==1` will return `False`, and `7/2==1` as well (in fact, only `p=2` will give True). But `8%2` is 0, and `7%2` is 1.

Comment: Simply put, the modulo operator ([other explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664301/how-does-modulus-divison-work)) says for `p%x`: extract x from p as long as possible. So 8%2 => 8, then 6, then 4, then 0. Done. And 7%2 => 7, then 5, then 3, then 1 and done (since 1-2 will return a negative number).

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra: Ah, I get it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for i,_ in enumerate(credit_card):
    if i%2:
        credit_card[i] *= 2
```

or if you want to be fancy:

```
 credit_card=[credit_card[i]*(2**(i%2)) for i in range(len(credit_card))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> 
>>> list(map(lambda x: x*2 if l.index(x)%2 else x, l))
[1, 4, 3, 8]
```