# modifying iterator in for loop in python

Tags: python

> @ Padraic Cunningham Let me know if you want me to delete the
>   question.

I am new to python. I want to skip some iterator values based on some condition. This is easy in C but in python I am having a hard time.

So please help me in understanding why the code here loops 100 times instead of 10.

```
 for i in range(100):
    print i
    i = i +10
```

**edit**: I understand there is option to change step size of for loop. But I am interested in dynamically changing the iterator variable, like we can do in C. Okay, i get it, for loop is different in python than in C. Easy way to do is use the while loop, I did that in my code and it worked. Thank you community!

Comment: Even in C, it is _always_ a bad idea to modify the iterating variable during a loop.

Comment: Based on the code you have shown, you should read the docs on [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range). Look at what `step` does.

Comment: I understand I can change the step size to 10, but I want to change the step size arbitrarily during run time, lets say inside some 'if conditions'. I also understand it is a bad idea to change the iterating variable, but I still wish to do that.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan There is a valid reason for this: I am processing a string that has been split, and in some cases I want to join two of the parts, e.g. I want to join '+' with the '5' that follows it. Then when I find the plus, I append the 5 and increase the variable in order to skip the 5. I am sure there are other valid situations. The use of the word "always" should be avoided: even GoTo has its place, we just don't trust students to use it wisely.

Comment: @user3079666 Please interpret my (six year old) comment in context. Are you using a `for` loop to meet your (valid) usecase, like the question asker is doing? If no, then your response is targeting a strawman. If yes, then please use the right tool: a `while` loop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The for loop is walking through the iterable `range(100)`.

Modifying the current value does not affect what appears next in the iterable (and indeed, you could have any iterable; the next value might not be a number!).

**Option 1 [use a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363138/scope-of-python-variable-in-for-loop):**

```
i = 0
while i < 100:
    i += 4
```

**[Option 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990121/how-do-i-loop-through-a-python-list-by-twos), use the built in step size argument of range:**

```
 for i in range(0,100,10):
       pass
```

---

This example may make it clearer why your method doesn't make much sense:

```
for i in [1,2,3,4,5,'cat','fish']:
    i = i + i
    print i
```

This is entirely valid python code (string addition is defined); modifying the iterable would require something unintuitive.

[See here for more information on how iterables work, and how to modify them dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols)

Comment: thank you the while loop worked for me. Will read more about the iterator concept in python.

Comment: while it makes sense in the context of python, python doesn't make sense in the context of a for loop.  By the time you write a for loop, it is both desirable and conventional to have this kind of control without reducing to the lower level while loop.  However, in *scripting* languages, such as BASH, it is consistent. Is python a scripting language? I can compile it...

Comment: Yes, "why does this happen [what is the technical mechanism]" and "for what reason did the language authors program it to happen this way" are related questions, but I only answered the first one here. Python early on made the decision to use first-class objects where other languages wouldn't, and this often causes confusion for non-python natives (like default arguments in functions), myself included. In this case, it is "pythonic" for the iterator to be a first-class object with an "__in__" method, instead of a syntactic structure that gets expanded by a compiler, imo

Comment: I agree that python loops can be quirky! Another example: they don't establish scopes, like many other languages would

Answer (score 4):

If you want to update an iterator, you can do something like that :

```
iterator= iter(range(100))
for i in iterator:
    print (i)
    for k in range(9): next(iterator)
```

But no practical interest !

Comment: Huh I owe you an apology - the confusion is caused by this absolutely [baffling bug](https://snipboard.io/RFuVUX.jpg) in my Python 3.7 (provided by conda). Miraculously, this bug makes your otherwise correct code run incorrectly, and my unnecessary code run correctly! Sorry for the confusion, a bug this catastrophic is mind boggling to me

Comment: Ahh solved - not a bug, but an extremely unintuitive interactive interpreter [behaviour](https://snipboard.io/9jPVlL.jpg) of `iter` whereby every return value of `next()` is printed (unless like in my example, assigned to a variable). How awful, sorry again!

Answer (score 3):

To do this use a while loop. Changing the iterator in a for loop will not change the amount if times it iterates Instead you can do

```
i=0
while i < 100:
    print i
    i = i +10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try this code it should work.

```
for i in range(100)[::10]:
    print i
```

The [::10] works like string slicing. [first position to start at: position to stop at:number to steps to make in each loop]

I didn't use the first two values so these are set to the default of first position and last position. I just told it to make steps of 10.