# Possible to skip lines in a for statement?

Tags: python

Is it possible to skip lines in a for statement? i.e....

```
for line in xrange(len(lines)):
    if line is True and line+1 is True and line+2 is True
        do something....
```

I'd like to skip ahead to line+3 in the next for loop after this one, because I have already looked at line+1 and line+2.

I have looked at continue and break as solutions but they do not seem to really solve the issue.

EDIT - To add on some clarification....
The data (text files) I am looking at don't simply come in sets of 3....I am going through football game logs...to give an example of code:
Denver kicks off to Kansas City
Kansas City returns the ball to the 20 yard line
Kansas City offense, Q1 and 15:00 left to go
Kansas City uses shotgun and gains 6 yards
Denver called a dime defense

The last 3 lines would basically be a play and would give me all the pertinent info I need (Offense, Defense, plays called, yards gained, etc)... But the first two lines are a kickoff and I do not want to process those lines..

Hopefully this will provide clarity.

Comment: It would help if you gave a clearer picture of the overall purpose of the code. What are the `lines`? What kind of pattern are you trying to detect? Supposing that the condition in the `if` statement *isn't* met; should you then try an "overlapping" position? Or you you actually want to *always* consider the source data in discrete sets of 3 lines? Because in that case there's a very neat duplicate I could refer you to.

Comment: seems duplicate with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2990152/4026902

Answer (score 0):

You could increment `line` by 3 every time:

```
for line in xrange(len(lines), 3):
```

Also, it seems that you are using Python 2 because of the `xrange`. Unless you have a specific reason for doing so, I would suggest that you use Python 3 because Python 2 has been deprecated.

In Python 3, you would write this as:

```
for line in range(len(lines), 3):
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this isn't going to be the most optimal solution but

```
for i in xrange(0,len(lines)-2,3):
    if lines(i) and lines(i+1) and lines(i+2):
        do something...
```

`xrange` will act in steps of 3, skipping to line3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either

```py
for line in xrange(2, len(lines)):
    # do something
```

or

```py
for line in xrange(len(lines)):
    if line < 2:
        continue
    # else, do something
```

Answer (score 0):

A pythonic solution without indexes

```
import itertools as it

lst = [True, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True]
glen = 3
grouped = zip(*[iter(lst)]*glen)
for g, i in zip(grouped, it.count()):
    if all(g):
        print(g, i)
```

Produces

```
(True, True, True) 0
(True, True, True) 2
```

It assumes the checking on boolean `True` is generic, i.e. it can be zero, an empty list, etc. If it needs to be specific to  the value `True` we must change the call to `all`