# Python function Loop to read excel files and run the code

Tags: python, excel, loops, for-loop, automation

I have code that compares 2 csv files and generates an output from them. I have around 50 csv files to compare. In the end i will have 25 csv as output. Is there a loop function which i can just run one code and generate  25 output?

All the filenames and their comparison names are in one excel sheet which can help.

```
FileA FileB    outputname=FileAB
FileC FileD    outputname=FileCD
FileE FileF    outputname=FileEF
```

My code starts like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file1 = 'oldfile.csv'
file2 = 'newfile.csv'

df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
df2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
```

and at the end i save the csv file:

```
df.to_csv(file_name, index=False)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Do you have a question?

Comment: @Luke Is there a loop function which i can just run one code and generate 25 output as i mentioned above ?

Comment: @Lea123 Your approach is correct. You need to read the file names from the CSV file and inside the loop, you need to compare files and generate a new loop. If you have any specific questions please ask. Don't expect the complete answer from here.

Comment: put the file names in a list. Then iterate through the list  by two's. The first file name would be i and the second would be i+1 most likey. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990121/how-do-i-loop-through-a-list-by-twos